# Question on groups of order $pq$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$, $p>q$  and $p$, $q$ are primes. Then prove that
>
> 1. If $q\mid p-1$ then there exists a non abelian group of order $pq$.
> 2. Any two non-abelian groups of order $pq$ are isomorphic.

I have proved that if $q\not\mid p-1$ then $G$ is cylic . But how to prove this one I have no idea.
Any kind of hint is very much welcome. This problem is in Herstein book, page 75.

Comment: Do you know what a semi-direct product is?

Comment: See Hall M. The theory of groups, sec.4.4, p.49.

Comment: This may help as well. http://books.google.com/books?id=KVeXG163BggC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=p+divides+q-1+group&source=bl&ots=quVK9nYCMQ&sig=qyU8XhMRU6LhuEN4awxzer2I0d8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aqRvUd6vBaaBywGk04DABA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=p%20divides%20q-1%20group&f=false

Comment: D&F has a whole section on this.

Answer (score 8):

If $q\mid p-1$ then $\rm{Aut}(C_p)$ has a unique subgroup of order $q$, and the map embedding $C_q$ in $\rm{Aut}(C_p)$ gives a semidirect product, which is not abelian (easy to check).

On the other hand, if $G$ is some other non-abelian group of order $pq$ then it is an easy exercise that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$ and since $G$ also has a subgroup of order $q$, it must be a semidirect product. But since the subgroup of order $q$ in $\rm{Aut}(C_p)$  was unique, the only possibility is the one we already accounted for.

Comment: Why is that $q-$ order subgroup unique?

Comment: @Martund Because the automorphism group in question is cyclic.