# $A_5$ has no subgroup of order 15 and 20

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Show that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order 15 and 20.

I have been thinking about this problem for so much time but I'm still clueless. Can anyone tell me how to do this problem? Thanks.

I looked up online and saw some proofs with simple groups or Sylow Theorem. Can somebody solve this problem without using simple groups or Sylow Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: How do you prove any group of order 15 is cyclic? I looked upon this but this still needs Sylow Theorem or something.

Comment: @user93383 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365261/question-on-groups-of-order-pq

Comment: Sylow Theory is really good to be able to use here. This problem screams for Sylow Theory.

Comment: If Sylow theory is out, Semi Direct products might also be too advanced.

Comment: I'm not sure Sylow theorems  can help a lot here...Now, without using simplicity of $\;A_5\;$ is, for me, completely impossible to prove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A question on a proof that $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231504/a-question-on-a-proof-that-a-5-has-no-subgroup-of-order-20)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

Prove the following:

**Claim:** If a group $\;G\;$ has a subgroup $\;H\;$ of index $\;n\;$ then it has a *normal* subgroup contained in $\;H\;$ and of index at most $\;n!\;$

**Proof:** Hint: make $\;G\;$ act on the left cosets of $\;H\;$, look at the induced homomorphism $\;G\to S_n\;$ and to its kernel...

From the above follows that a simple group cannot have subgroups of index $\;n\;$ **if** the order of the group doesn't divide $\;n!\;$ .

Comment: doesn't $20$ divide $5!$?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer Yes, it does...it even divides $\;|A_n|=\frac{5!}2=60\;$ , yet that is **not* what is implied in my answer. Read carefully again and try to focus on the difference between order of a group and *index of that group* in the bigger group.

Answer (score 4):

On contrary Suppose there is subgroup of $A_5$ with order $20$ say H .Consider $\alpha \notin H$ and $\alpha$ has order 5.Our Aim is to show that every element of order 5 belong to H as there are 24 elements of order 5 in $A_5$ our assumption will be wrong in this case.
 Then $A_5$=$H \cup \alpha H \cup \alpha^2H$.
As Now cosider $\alpha^3 \in $ $H$ or $\alpha H$ or $ \alpha^2H$.
Which is contradication this is because if $\alpha^3 \in $ $H$ then $(\alpha^3)^2$=$\alpha^6$=$\alpha$ $\in H$ which in not possible .
Similarly $\alpha^3 \in $ $ \alpha^2H$ as this means $\alpha \in H$ which is contradicts 
Similarly $\alpha^3 \in $ $ \alpha H$ as this means $\alpha^2 \in H$ which is contradicts 
Therefore $ \alpha \in H$ this is true for every $ \alpha $ of order 5 hence H contain 24 element of order 5 which is contradiacation with fact that its order is 20
Similar to show about 15 order subgroup not possible

Comment: why $A_5=H \cup \alpha H \cup \alpha^2H$ is true?

Comment: Also How do you know that there are 24 elements the in order of 5 in $A_5$?

Comment: just by calculation lol

Answer (score 2):

$\langle (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3) \rangle = A_5$ notice. If $A_5$ had a subgroup of order 15, then it must (by Cauchy) contain an element of order 5 and an element of  3. But then the order of any group generated by those elements must be of order 15, 30 or 60. It cannot be 30, else then the group would be normal (contradicting simplicity) since it is of index 2. You can show that in fact any three cycle and any 5 cycle must generate the whole group.

Doing this without Sylow and Simplicity........might be hard.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the answer for $|H|= 15$. I belive the proof for $|H|= 20$ is similar.

Fist, I will state the "Representation Theorem": Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ with index $n$. Thus there exists $N \subseteq H$, with $N \trianglelefteq G$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$.

(Cayley's theorem is a particular case of these one)

Now, suppose that $H$ is a subgrup of $A_5$ with order $15$, thus $|G: H| = 4$. It follows by the Representation Theorem that there exists a subgroup $N$ of $H$ that is normal in $G$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$. However, $A_5$ is a simple group, thus we have only two possibilities for such normal subgroup $N$,

- If $N$ is trivial, then $G/N = G$ must be a subgroup of $S_4$, what is a contradiction of Lagrange's theorem.
- If $N$ is $G$, then $G$ is contained in a proper subgroup of itself (that is $H$), contradiction!
  Therefore, such $N$ does not exists. Hence there is no subgroup $H$ with order 15 in $A_5$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, let $G$ be a nontrivial finite group and $X_G$ the set of all the proper subgroups of $G$: $$X_G:=\{H\subseteq G\mid H\le G \wedge H\ne G\}.$$ If $G$ is *simple*, then:

$$[G:H]!\ge|G|, \space\forall H\in X_G \tag 1$$

In fact, for $H\in X_G$, the group $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, and this action has trivial kernel$^\dagger$. So, $G$ embeds into $S_{[G:H]}$, whence $(1)$.

The constraint $(1)$ means that finite simple groups cannot have "relatively big" subgroups. As for your case, from $(1)$ follows that $A_5$ can't have subgroups of order $15$, $20$ and $30$ (this latter is ruled out by the very simplicity of $A_5$, though), because $[60:k]!<60$ for $k=15, 20, 30$.

---

$^\dagger$For $H\in X_G$, we get: $K:=\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}\lneq G$, and thence $K=\{1\}$ for the simplicity of $G$.