# Prove that $A_5$ does not have a subgroup of order 15, 20, nor 30 (without using simple group and Sylow's Theorem)

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Show that $A_5$ does not have a subgroup of order 15, 20, nor 30.

I looked up other posts such as the one below, but they used some things we don't cover in the course.

[$A_5$ has no subgroup of order 15 and 20](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545126/a-5-has-no-subgroup-of-order-15-and-20)

Instead, we did a similar example in class:

> Show that $A_4$ has no subgroups of order 6.

> Suppose $H \preceq A_4$
> with $|H| = 6$. Then $[A_4: H] = 2$ and so $H \unlhd A_4$. Therefore,
> $(aH)^2 = H \forall a \in A_4$. This means $a^2 \in H \forall a \in
>  A_4$. We can compute to show that $A_4$ has 9 elements of the form
> $a^2$, and by above they must all be in $H$. But this is a
> contradiction since $|H| = 6$. Hence no such $H$ exist.

But the problem with trying to apply a similar proof to my question is that, since $[A_5: H]$ = 4, we cannot say that $H \unlhd A_5$. Hence, we cannot say $(aH)^4 = H$ since we cannot form the factor group $A_5/H$. If that is the case, how else can I solve the question without using simple group and  Sylow's Theorem.

Comment: Do you know about actions? Do you know that if $G$ has a subgroup $H$ of index $n$, that induces a morphism $G\to S_n$ with kernel contained in $H$?

Comment: I didn't ask you to list the things you know (and it's "kernel", not "kernal"). I asked if you knew two specific things. The answer should have been either "yes" or "no."

Comment: No to both questions.

Comment: Groups of order $15$ must be cyclic, but $A_5$ has no elements of order $15$. For order $30$ you can use a similar argument as you did for $A_4$. Order $20$ cannot contain two $5$-cycles that are not powers of each other, but conjugating a $5$-cycle with any element of order $2$ will give you two such cycles. Now try to fill in the details and post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I probably misunderstood the gist of your argument, but $A_5$ does contain copies of the dihedral group $D_5$. After all, it has six Sylow $5$-subgroups, each with a normalizer of order ten. So it is possible to conjugate a 5-cycle with an element of order two, and get the inverse 5-cycle. True, this won't happen with *all* the elements of order two. The normalizer of a Sylow 5 in $S_5$ is the holomorph $C_5\rtimes C_4$, and when you intersect that with $A_5$ you get $D_5$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't work it out in detail, and you are correct about the dihedral copies. You need to do a bit more work and verify that there aren't enough elements of order $2$ (and none of order 4, of course) that normalize the cyclic subgroup, so you cannot build a subgroup of order $20$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, we've pretty much narrowed it down to the subgroup of order $20$.

To tackle that,  note that if $H\le A_5$ with $\mid H\mid=20$, then let $A_5$ act on the set of $3$ left cosets $A_5/H$.  We get a  homomorphism from $A_5$ into $S_3$, which is non-trivial:  it's kernel $\cap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}\subset H$.

---

Briefly,  the homomorphism is defined by letting $\varphi (g)$ be the element of $S_3$ corresponding to the permutation of the cosets brought about by applying $g$.  That's let $\bar{g_1},\bar{g_2},\bar{g_3}$ be the cosets.  Multiplying by $g$ on the left permutes them.  We get $\bar{g_1}\to \bar {gg_1},\,\bar {g_2}\to\bar{gg_2}$ and $\bar {g_3}\to\bar{gg_3}$.  It's easy to see that $g$ takes different cosets to different cosets.   So we really do have an element of $S_3$.

---

Now to continue note that $A_5=\langle(12)(34),(135)\rangle$. And $(12)(34)(135)$ has order $5$.  Then $e=\varphi ((12)(34)(135))=\varphi ((12)(34))\varphi ((135))\implies \varphi ((12)(34))=\varphi ((135))=e$, because the orders divide $2$ and $3$ (and are the same). So we've reached a contradiction.

Comment: The OP said he is not familiar with the induced morphism into the symmetric group.

Comment: I know @ArturoMagidin, but shouldn't he get acquainted with it?

Comment: Then you would need to explain it, not just mention it as if they know what you are talking about.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok, I added a little bit.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it definitely does help. I won't be able to use this, but it adds to my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

A *very* low-tech approach.

Since $30$ is an integer of the form $4k+2$ a subgroup with $30$ elements would automatically admit a subgroup with $15$ elements. By Cauchy's theorem a subgroup of $A_5$ with $15$ elements would contain a $5$-cycle $\varphi$ and a $3$-cycle $\gamma$. However $\varphi\gamma$ or $\varphi\gamma^2$ necessarily contains a transposition in its cycle decomposition, which makes $|\langle \varphi,\gamma\rangle|$ even.

About subgroups of order $20$: in this case we would have a $5$-cycle $\varphi$ (which we may assume to be $(12345)$) and a double transposition $\delta$. Up to conjugation we may freely assume that $1$ is a fixed point of $\delta$, and restrict our attention to three cases:

1. $\delta=(23)(45)$. In this case $\delta\varphi$ has order $3$ and we are doomed.
2. $\delta=(24)(35)$. In this case the product between $\delta$ and its conjugated $(14)(35)$ has order $3$. We are doomed.
3. $\delta=(25)(34)$. Here we may take the identity, all the double transpositions given by $\varphi^k \delta \varphi^{-k}$ and the powers of $\varphi$ to actually have a subgroup of $A_5$ with order $10$. That is not enough. Since we cannot take any extra double transposition, we need to take other $10$ $5$-cycles from the $5$-cycles in $A_5$ which are not powers of $\varphi$. At that point we would have more than half the $5$-cycles in $A_5$, and the span would be $A_5$. Or: by conjugating $\delta$ via one of these new $5$-cycles we would get a double transposition of the "bad" kind, being doomed again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof that $A_5$ does not contain subgroups of order $20$.

Let $H<A_5$ and $|H|=20$.

1. Not all cycles of length $5$ are contained in $H$ (since $A_5$ has $24$ cycles of length $5$).
2. If $a$ is a cycle of length $5$ and $a\notin H$, then $a^2,a^3\notin H$ and the cosets $H,Ha,Ha^2$ are pairwise distinct, so
   $$
   G=H\cup Ha\cup Ha^2.
   $$
3. Which of the three cosets contains $a^3$? Contradiction.

**Adding.** I find this helpful.

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $A_5$, then either $|H|\leq12$ or $H=A_5$.

*Proof* without using Sylow's theorem, the simplicity of the group $A_n$, and the notion of a group action. But the proof uses the Lagrange theorem.

1. There exists a cycle $a$ of length $5$ which is not contained in the subgroup $H$. Then $a^2,a^3,a^4\notin H$ and so the cosets $H,Ha,Ha^2,Ha^3,Ha^4$ are pairwise different. Hence $|G:H|\geq5$ and $|H|\leq12$.
2. Let all cycles of length $5$ be contained in $H$. Since
   $$
   (i_1i_2i_3i_4i_5)(i_1i_2i_5i_4i_3)=(i_1i_3i_2),
   $$
   it follows that all cycles of length $3$ are contained in $H$. There are $24$ cycles of length $5$ and $20$ cycles of length $3$. So $|H|>44\Rightarrow|H|=60\Rightarrow H=A_5$.